# Install package in grater version with string in name

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a problem do add to requirements.txt package with string in version and install this in grater version. I need this to development process when i push commit i create a new package and on main project i can update them by: `pip install -r .\requirements.txt` without manually changing version.
The version name looks like:

Master package name: `1.0.1`

dev or other branch package: branch_name.master_version.build_version e.g.
`dev.1.0.1.3333, branch-1.0.1.3333, branch-bla-bla-12.1.0.1.3333`

and i want in requirements checking get only grater master_version.build_version in choosing branch:

```
dev.1.0.1.3333 checking bigger then dev.*
branch-1.0.1.3333 checking bigger then branch-1.*
branch-bla-bla-12.1.0.1.3333 checking bigger then branch-bla-bla-12.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i had a bug in my setup.py
When number is in schema: branch_name.version_number.build_number work as i expect.